# LINQ filter by field in joining table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, join

On all my tables I have an IsDeleted field so that I can toggle records on and off. I'm trying to figure out how to use LinqToSql to filter out deleted records in the join table but I don't know how to identify that table in the linq query. Here is my basic table definition:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItemsEntity>().ToTable("MenuItems")
    .HasMany(m => m.UserGroups).WithMany(ur => ur.MenuItems)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("MenuItems_UserGroups")
            .MapLeftKey("MenuItemId")
            .MapRightKey("UserGroupId");
    });
```

and here is my linq statement so far:

```
var menuItems = _ctx.MenuItems.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.ParentId == parentId 
&& x.UserGroups.Any(r => !r.IsDeleted && r.Id == userGroupId));
```

This adds the IsDeleted check for tables MenuItems and UserGroups, but not for MenuItems_UserGroups.

Any ideas?